# Does PrimeFaces Extensions components use OmniFaces?

Tags: primefaces, omnifaces, primefaces-extensions

I was looking for any omnifaces import in PrimeFaces Extensions API but did not found.

http://primefaces-extensions.github.io/reports/apidocs/index.html

Question in title. Any ideas? Or I'm on wrong way and PE don't use OmniFaces?

Comment: You wouldn't see imports in the API anyway. The javadoc is generated for project's own classes, not its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

No.

See `<dependencies>` in the [PFE project POM](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/pom.xml). That's all.